# How do I get all the values of different strings that end with a certain word

Tags: python, data-science

My dataframe has a **column** called `Borough` which contains values like these:

"east toronto", "west toronto", "central toronto" and "west toronto", along with other region names.

Now I want a regular expression which gets me the data of every entry that ends with "toronto". How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
tronto_data = df_toronto[df_toronto['Borough'] = .*Toronto$].reset_index(drop=True)
tronto_data.head(7)
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can use "your_string.endswith('toronto")"

Comment: I have a dataframe. In one particular column of the dataframe i have data containing like east toronto, west toronto, middle toronto, north toronto,west, toronto, quebec, 18yrk and many more.

I want a regex expression which can return me data rows that contains data of all regions of toronto data

Answer (score 0):

If the data is well formatted you can split the string on the space and access the final word, comparing it to Toronto. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['west toronto', 'central toronto', 'some place']})

mask_df = df['column'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

which returns:

```
     0         1
0   west     toronto
1   central  toronto
2   some     place
```

you can then access the final column to work out the rows that end with Toronto.

```
toronto_df = df[mask_df[1]=='toronto']
```

**Edit:**

Did not know there was a string method `.endswith` which is the better way to do this. However, this solution does provide two columns which maybe useful.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Code_10 refers in a comment that you can use string.endswith.. try below->

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['east toronto', 'west toronto', 'other', 'central toronto']})
df_toronto = df[df['city'].str.endswith('toronto')]
#df_toronto.head()
```